# Integrals with multiple valued functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Currently I'm struggling with this question:

Use residue theory to verify the following: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha}}{(x+9)^2} \operatorname{d}x = \frac{\pi(1-\alpha)}{4\cos\left(\alpha\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$  $-1 <\alpha < 1$,  $\alpha\neq 0$

It feels like I'm struggling a bit (a lot) with branch cuts, how should I approach this question, can someone give me a hint of how to start with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a keyhole contour might do the trick.

Comment: If I do make a keyhole contour, would it be okay to quote "Jordan's lemma" to prove that the the "circles" becomes 0 or is that wrong?

Comment: I think so, yes, so long as all criteria of the lemma are met. You will need to show the large and small circles go to zero, leaving only the integral above the positive $x$ axis (which you want to find) and the integral under the positive $x$ axis, and of course any remaining residues.

Comment: A keyhole contour works well, but this has nothing to do with Jordan's lemma (at least not the way it's usually stated). Better to argue using direct estimation.